# Angular route management with oidc client

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router, oidc-client

I have an Angular application in which I am specifying a route to which the user should be redirected once they log in.

**My OIDC configuration (app.module)**

```
 AuthOidcModule.forRoot({
  config: {
    authority: '*https://myurl*',
    redirectUrl: 'https://myurl/callback',
    postLogoutRedirectUri: "https://myurl/login",
    clientId: 'my-client-id',
    scope: "my-scopes",
  },
}),
```

When redirected to this route, the component I specified in my app-routing.module should run, but I placed a debugger and it never runs.

**app-routing.module**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'callback',
    component: CallbackComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
  
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I noticed that the problem may be related to the fact that my redirect route is 'callback' but oidc client concatenates some parameters for me by the url and that is why it never matches 'callback'

How could I solve this?